# Check unique random value against database with minimal resource use

Tags: php, mysql, database, unique

This is more of a best practice question. I'm generating a random string identifier with the following parameters:

- length: 7 characters
- seed: A-Za-z0-9 (lowercase + uppercase alphabet and numbers)

I need to check if that string exists in the database before I'm inserting it. I can do that in two ways:

1. Run a `do...while` loop. In it, generate a random string and each time, query the database with `COUNT(*)` until `count === 0`.
2. First get all existing unique strings from the database with a single query, then run a `do...while` loop to generate a random string that's not in the fetched array.

It's obvious to me that the second method is technically less resource intensive for the database server, because there's only a single query, as opposed to querying over and over. So I'm leaning towards that method, but I see two potential caveats:

Large databases, and time passed between fetching and inserting.

- **Large database results:** How many rows can be in a query result before I need to consider switching to the first method? In other words, when is the strain of a large result set on the database server lower than running multiple subsequent queries? 1,000 results? 5,000? 20,000?
- **Time between fetch & insert:** If I use the second method, I see a risk when two or more users try to run the same function simultaneously. The first user's result set (of unique strings fetched from the database) may not include the other user's unique string that has just been added 2ms after the query. This could produce duplicates in the database.

Is the second method actually feasable in production, or is it just a dream?

Comment: You need to analyse the likelihood of generating the same random string twice. If it's small enough then you might be better off just trying to insert it and checking if there's any uniqueness constraint violation errors in your query.

Answer (score 1):

The second option does not seem practical to me. If you have only a few rows in the table, you have low risk of collisions, if you have many rows, the risk of collision increase but it is not memory efficient on the php-side to fetch all rows.

The first solution seems better to me.

But I think a third option can be used. Add a unique index on your random value in MySQL. Generate a random value, then try to insert it. Catch the error if a collision happen. That's efficient because MySQL is quick at checking if a value exist when it is indexed. You have no concurrency issue with this approach.

The only caveat (for all approaches) is when your number of rows in the table is high, you will have difficulties to find a yet unused value. To lower the risk of collision, you can increase the size of the random value. You could also create another table that contains unused values, and fill this table with an other algorithm when it has too few values.

Comment: You can generate 3x10^12 unique string sequences of length 7 using `AZaz09`. I think storage space will run out way before collisions start occurring.

Comment: If there are 3 billions unique string sequences and there is 3 million rows in the table, you have 1/1000 chance of having a collision. In that case, collisions *will* happen. It all depends on the scaling and the usage of this table actually (the OP does not indicate how it will be used).

Comment: 3 million = 10^6 and 10^6 / 10^12 = 1/10^6 which is one in a million. You'd expect 3 collisions in a table of 3 million rows. That's in no way a high rate of collisions. Collisions will happen, but we need to be realistic on the actual frequency and write code according to that instead of introducing a large overhead to handle a few marginal cases. This is referring to any "check before you insert" solutions.

Comment: Yes, my bad, billion is just 10e9, not 10e12. In all cases, the collision discussion was just a side note.